# camel recipientlist calling rest service is not returning json response to browser

Tags: json, web-services, apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse

I have the following camel route :

```
<camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="addressRoute">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:addressSearchEndpoint"/>
        <removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*"/>
        <recipientList>
            <simple>http4://<someURL>/PostcodeAnywhere/Interactive/RetrieveByAddress/v1.20/json.ws?Key=<someKey>&amp;amp;Address=WR2%206NJ&amp;amp;Company=&amp;amp;UserName=PROVI11136</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>
```

which uses  a recipient list to invoke an external REST service.
The issue I am having is that although I see the response in the log:

[               qtp269562434-42] addressRoute                   INFO
[{"Udprn":"52269655","Company":"","Department":"","Line1":"2 Wylcotts","Line2":"Moseley Road","Line3":"Hallow","Line4":"","Line5":"","PostTown":"Worcester","County":"Worcestershire","Postcode":"WR2 6NJ","Mailsort":"94141","Barcode":"(WR26NJ4D7)","Type":"Residential"}]

it does not appear in the browser when I invoke

http://localhost:9191/cxf/addresssearch/

Anything I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: I solved by removing the <log tag at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removing the log tag at the end.